# Android memory leaks designing layouts

Tags: android, memory-management, android-layout, memory-leaks

My application is designed with all layouts in res folder as application is image processing; it deals with large sized bitmaps, and is giving `out of memmory error`. I want to know what is the good approach.

1. Designing layouts programatically
2. Using layouts from res folder.

If I am designing all layouts in program I can cleanup all layouts myself in `onDestroy()` method which I can't if layouts are declared in XML.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use the XML way because is more faster and reusable.. if you don't pass your current's activity context to another activity, android will take care of cleaning your layouts..

You can clean the inflated layouts in onDestroy() if you want, exactly how you do with the coded layouts. But I don't think it's necessary.

Comment: You can't clean layouts either way. You could try to set all layout variables to null or set an empty layout and call gc afterwards, but calling gc manually is not really supported and reasonable with android.

Comment: Well I think the "clean" word in java means: set the references to null :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using large bitmaps and changing them after creating them make sure that you call [recycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) on all bitmaps that are not used anymore. This is the only point where a manual Memory Management in Android is needed.

Recycle will free the native storage that the bitmaps takes up in the current Android Versions. It is unlikely that the memory used by your layout will cause the memory problems. Concentrate on the Bitmaps Objects you are creating.